# What other than java.lang packages are imported automatically in the JShell?

Tags: java, jshell

I've observed that in the JShell session, not only package "java.lang", but quite a few other packages (that are not imported automatically in the Java class files, e.g. `LinkedList`, `Math` and several other types) seem to be imported, by default.

I wonder, what other packages are available, by default, in the JShell session, and what motivates this distinction from the normal class files?

I could not find anything on [JEP 222](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/222), neither the motivation of this auto/implicit import , nor the documentation of - what is actually imported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run `/import` to find out:

```
jshell> /import
|    import java.io.*
|    import java.math.*
|    import java.net.*
|    import java.nio.file.*
|    import java.util.*
|    import java.util.concurrent.*
|    import java.util.function.*
|    import java.util.prefs.*
|    import java.util.regex.*
|    import java.util.stream.*
```

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jshell.html